# How to troubleshoot an allegedly missing module (google.oauth2)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-module

I wanted to experiment with [connecting to Google Calendar APIs with a service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequests).

The example code requires `google.oauth2`, which for some reason I cannot import:

```
C:\Users\yop>pip3 install google
Requirement already satisfied: google in c:\users\yop\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (2.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in c:\users\yop\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from google) (4.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>=1.2 in c:\users\yop\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from beautifulsoup4->google) (1.9.5)

C:\Users\yop>python
Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 19:29:22) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import google
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'
```

**How can I troubleshoot this?** The module seems to be installed, for the right Python version.

In contrast, consider the `arrow` module, which is installed the same way:

```
C:\Users\yop>pip3 install arrow
Requirement already satisfied: arrow in c:\users\yop\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (0.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in c:\users\yop\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from arrow) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\yop\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil->arrow) (1.12.0)

C:\Users\yop>python
Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 19:29:22) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import arrow
>>> arrow.__file__
'C:\\Users\\yop\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\arrow\\__init__.py'
```

Comment: @AlirezaTajadod: yes, same error.BUT you pointed me to the right direction, the module to be installed is different (https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/master/docs/oauth.md) → would you mind to turn this into an answer (I installed both modules and it works OK)

Comment: maybe you can try to install the module with the right interpreter: `python -m pip install google`

Comment: As @AlirezaTajadod pointed out, that's the wrong module. `pip3 install google-auth-oauthlib` works if you need to use `google.oauth2`

Comment: @Axe319: yes, I modified their answer to include all the links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modules to install in order to `import google` are [`google-auth` and `google-auth-oauthlib`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/master/docs/oauth.md):

```
pip3 install google-auth google-auth-oauthlib
```

After that you will be able to `import google.oauth2`

Comment: Thanks for the hint - I rewrote somehow your answer to clearly point to the docs, what to import etc.